# discord.js bot cannot read "channel" property

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i get this error when i run the bot. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined`

here is the code

```js
client.on('ready', ()=>{
    let guild = client.guilds.get(`635447148904972298`);
    let channel = guild.channels.get(`643131583599214643`)
    setInterval(function() {
        channel.setName('Member Count: ${guild.memberCount}')
    }, 60000)
    
})
```

Comment: That's because `client.guilds.get(\`635447148904972298\`)` returned `undefined`, so `guild.channels` tried to "read property 'channels' of undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that i just forgot to add the last digit of the channel ID.